# How does Gmail decide to thread email messages?

Tags: gmail, gmail-conversations

Sometimes I'll notice false positives (includes an email that isn't part of the thread) and false negatives (misses an email that should have been part of the thread). How does Gmail decide which messages should and shouldn't be part of a thread?

Comment: don't blame Gmail, it's the best mail-threader I always have seen ;-)

Comment: I've never seen false positives, I'm surprised that those even exist.

Comment: @neo, There are better ones.

Comment: @mbillard, Well if it goes by title of the message, false positives are bound to exist.

Comment: https://blogs.fsfe.org/stargrave/archives/80 and https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gmail/ogAioUSE5Es/1maEElbKsW4J

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The following conditions must be met:

1. The subject must be similar (e.g. `test` and `re: test` will work; but `test` and `test 123` won't).
2. The sender must be a part of the thread OR the in-reply-to header must be used.

The in-reply-to header can be used via Gmail's interface by simply replying to the thread. This is what enables forwarded messages to be a part of the same thread even though the sender is different.

If you want more information, you can check out [my blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20221018211910/http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/08/how-does-email-threading-work-in-gmail.html) where I posted more detailed information about my findings.

Comment: Funny, there is a in-reply-to field, and google does not use that...

Comment: See [this answer](https://www.quora.com/How-does-Gmail-decide-which-emails-go-into-which-threads) over on Quora - he says it is threaded by use of the **Message-ID:** header. Does anyone KNOW for sure how gmail decides to thread conversations?

Comment: And does anyone know if there is a way to get Gmail to accept other reply prefixes than "Re"? E-mail clients configured to use Norwegian like to use "Sv" or "Svar", which is a translation of "Reply", as prefix when replying

Answer (score 17):

The short answer:  **the subject line**.

Google states:

> a conversation will break off into a new thread if the subject line of the conversation is changed, or if the conversation reaches over 100 messages.

[More info from Google](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=5900)

Comment: Yes, that is what also says in the second link I provided. 
I though it would be good to also give some background on the whole matter :)

Comment: I've seen it break between 60 and 80, so I'm not sure how reliable that article is. But it's close.

Comment: i've always seen it break at 60

Comment: It was experimentally established (as of 2014) that subject parts in [brackets] are ignored: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1048#issuecomment-42026092 .

Comment: Not sufficient.  If I have two people respond to the same Kijiji ad the subject line is identical, but they aren't in the same thread unless they are within a certain time window -- more than an hour less than 2 days.

Answer (score 4):

There are headers in an email message which contain information about which thread the email message belongs to. I don't know for sure that Gmail uses these headers, but I would be very surprised if it didn't. You can see the headers of an email message in Gmail.com by clicking the three dots and then "Show original".

If those headers don't exist, I presume Gmail will then fall back to guessing based on the subject line.

## Relevent email headers:

- `Message-ID`: every email message can include this header, and it is used to identify that email message uniquely. It can look like anything as long as it is unique, for instance, `199802242058.MAA24843@monk.via.net` is a valid Message-ID.
- `In-Reply-To`: this will contain the message ID of the email message that the current message is in response to. Gmail can use this information to put the message in the correct conversation.
- `References`: this will contain a list of all the message IDs of all the previous emails in the conversation, according to the software that sent the email message. This is more durable than `In-Reply-To`, in case the recipient doesn't have the previous message in the conversation, but does have some of the messages before that.

## References:

- Blog post by Wes Morgan (2012) [Understanding Email Headers, Part II - The Basics](https://wesmorgan.blogspot.com/2012/07/understanding-email-headers-part-ii.html)
- Quora answer [How does Gmail decide which emails go into which threads?](https://www.quora.com/How-does-Gmail-decide-which-emails-go-into-which-threads)

Comment: Really old thread but I do want to chime in that the other answers are more correct - whether or not GMail uses these at all I suppose is a question, but the subject line seems to be the actual threading data used, not the email headers shown above.