# How does Gmail deal with square brackets in subjects?

Tags: gmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Gmail decide to thread email messages?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/965/how-does-gmail-decide-to-thread-email-messages)

My web app sends out emails with subjects like this:

```
[some_user/some_project] Test 5 failed
[a_different_user/different_project] Test 5 failed
```

Unfortunately, Gmail groups these together in the same thread, which is really confusing for my users. What are the rules around how Google does this threading, and is there a scheme I can use which is functionally similar but where they wont get grouped like that?

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise: thanks for that. Those don't answer my question, so I made it more specific so that it's not a dup.

Comment: I suspect that Gmail is assuming the text in square brackets is a tag from a mailing list and so is ignoring it. You might try curly braces or parentheses, or separating the two pieces of information with a pipe or similar: `some_user/some_project | Test 5 failed`